# Google Maps API night theme for mobile phones

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

When using the Google Maps API for Android and IOS , is it possible to display the night theme which already exists in android after a certain time and in ios if you double click the home button.

Comment: would you know if their are any workaround perhaps using the javascript version that does have the feature to style the map. I ask because its required for a time sensitive project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps doesn't currently support style map for both Android and iOS.

You can submite a feature request over [here](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=code&ltmpl=phosting&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgmaps-api-issues%2Fissues%2Fentry%3Ftemplate%3DAndroid%2520API%2520v2%2520-%2520Feature%2520Request#identifier) to be added.